# When passing dynamic to method, the result is dynamic expression, even if it is not

Tags: c#, dynamic

In C# 5 when I tried to pass a dynamic as a method parameter the result for some reason became dynamic.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic value = "John";
        Find<int>(value).ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(object value)
    {
        //SOME LOGIC
        yield return default(T); //REAL RESULT
    }
}
```

`Find<T>(value)` has to return `IEnumerable<T>`. **Why compiler thinks it is dynamic?**
I know that `Find<int>(val as object).ToList();` solves this, but I want to understand **WHY** it happens.

Comment: There's a great blog about this from Eric Lippert - [Dynamic contagion, part one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/11/05/dynamic-contagion-part-one.aspx) and [Dynamic contagion, part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/11/08/dynamic-contagion-part-two.aspx)

Comment: @PatricHofman, I meant that if try to put dot after `Find<int>(value)` you'll se a message - 'dynamic expression. this operation will be resolved at runtime.`

Comment: @olegwx: Okay. Clear. Missed that from the question.

Comment: @petelids Eric Lippert's articles have moved since: [Dynamic contagion](https://ericlippert.com/2012/11/05/dynamic-contagion-part-one/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there could be a Find that matches another method than your Find at runtime, once you go dynamic, everything is dynamic, including resolving which method fits, so as soon as something is dynamic in an expression, the whole expression is dynamic.

For example there could be another method like

```
public static T Find<T>(sometype value)
{
   return default T;
}
```

This would be a better match at runtime if the dynamic was actually of type sometype, so as long as the compiler doesn't know what dynamic is it can't infer the return type since that type could be anything returned by the method that matches best AT RUNTIME.

So the compiler says it returns dynamic because that's it best bet, your method returns something else, but the compiler doesn't know yet if that method will be the one called.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, @RonanThibaudau. Thank you Ronan, in addition if you try to iterate he result `var result = Find<int>(value); var list = result.ToList();` you'll get an exception 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' says "Additional information: 'ConsoleApplication.Program.<Find>d__3<int>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'". And yes `result is IEnumerable<int>;` is **true**. That the strangest thing... It is **not a compiletime**, it is **runtime**...

Comment: @olegwx this too is expected while it may seem counter intuitive. ToList is an extension method, which means it actually is Enumerable.ToList(this IEnumerable<T> item). Extention methods rely on type information but also type inferrence (to know what the T is and call the proper Generic version). It's simply not compatible with dynamic, overall you're misusing dynamic there, it's there for a few use cases and linq is not one of them, i strongly avoid you do the minimum you wish to do with dynamic and revert to strongly typed right after, everything linq is based on types and typing inference

Answer (score 0):

dynamic is type unknown at compile time but in the runtime. So in the runtime it can be a string type and there could be a better match called Find(string value) which returns a different type. That's the reason the compiler is unable to tell you. It is resolved at runtime.