# How to generate and bind a column for each item in the collection property of items used as DataGrid's ItemsSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

The items source of my data grid is a collection of objects like:

```
Public Property Quarter As Integer
Public Property MyColumns() As New List(Of MyColumn)
```

Now I want to have a grid binding in a way that my resulting grid looks like

> -- Quarter  -- Column1 --  Column2 --  Column3  ....  ColumnX

All items in datasource will have same MyColumns.

Is there a way by which I can bind a collection to grid columns ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983033/how-do-i-dynamically-generate-columns-in-a-wpf-datagrid may give you a few ideas - basically wrap you property+collection objects into `ExpandoObject`s with property+(property for each item in collection) and apply the solution proposed there.

Comment: thanls for coming back Eugene, but to be honest I have used expandoObj before, infact never heard :( .. am trying it out but its getting messier as of now ...

Comment: It turns out that my first comment was a bit misleading(it is possible to do it so, but it will be far too complex). The most simple and direct solution is described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361013/wpf-dictionaryint-liststring-in-datagrid. It uses manual column generation and [binding to indexers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300.aspx#Path%5FSyntax).

Comment: I have added the solution as an answer. First part deals with arbitrary length collection, the second deals exactly with your case.

Comment: I also got the ExpandoObject thing working :) .... thanks for the tip learnt a new feature .. and its pretty exciting... you might wanna post that as second answer as that might be useful to the lot

Comment: and you know what, for autobinding, I needed property name as A B with a space in between .. n expando lets you have property names with spaces in them.. haha m going crazy on expando :P

Comment: If you want you can post your own solution with `ExpandoObject` - I'll gladly upvote it. Just do not forget that `dynamic` is ["contagious"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665111/when-passing-dynamic-to-method-the-result-is-dynamic-expression-even-if-it-is). Basically, as it is with every other tool, `dynamic` is the right tool for the right job. Used in a right place it can greatly simplify the development, while used in a wrong place it will deprive you of all the advantages conferred by the strong static typing (Intellisense, compile checks...).

Comment: o yea I understand that.. :) thanks for warning though !.... I will post my ans in a bit thanks

Comment: posted please suggest improvements if you can spot any thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. It is not the prettiest or the easiest but it is quite configurable. It is based mostly on the idea from the post [WPF: Dictionary<int, List<string>> in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361013/wpf-dictionaryint-liststring-in-datagrid), just turned into a more generalized version with a bit of Expressions and Reflection.

It will work whether items used as `ItemsSource` have the same or different amount of items contained in the respective collection property.

---

## Arbitrary length

Here are the required components:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Expressions = System.Linq.Expressions;

// See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132791/reflecting-over-all-properties-of-an-interface-including-inherited-ones
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static PropertyInfo GetInterfaceProperty(this Type type, String propName, Type returnType)
    {
        if (propName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propName");
        if (returnType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propType");

        return type.GetInterfaces()
            .Select(parentInterface =>
                parentInterface.GetProperty(propName, returnType))
            .Where(prop =>
                prop != null)
            .Single();
    }
}

public static class CollectionPropertyDataGridBindingHelper
{
    public static void RemoveAutoGeneratedColumns(this DataGrid dataGrid, String propertyName)
    {
        if (dataGrid == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dataGrid");
        if (propertyName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

        var autogeneratedColumns = dataGrid
            .Columns
            .OfType<DataGridBoundColumn>()
            .Where(col =>
                (col.Binding as Binding).Path.Path.Equals(propertyName));

        foreach (var autoColumn in autogeneratedColumns)
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Remove(autoColumn);
        }
    }


    public static void RegenerateColumns<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(
        this DataGrid dataGrid,
        Expressions.Expression<Func<TItem, IEnumerable<TPropertyCollectionItem>>> propertyExpression, 
        IEnumerable<TItem> items)
    {
        RegenerateColumns<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(dataGrid,
            propertyExpression,
            items,
            (index) =>
                String.Format("Column - {0}", index));
    }


    public static void RegenerateColumns<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(
        this DataGrid dataGrid, 
        Expressions.Expression<Func<TItem, IEnumerable<TPropertyCollectionItem>>> collectionPropertyExpression, 
        IEnumerable<TItem> items, 
        Func<Int32, String> formatHeader)
    {
        if (dataGrid == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dataGrid");
        if (collectionPropertyExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");
        if (items == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("items");
        if (formatHeader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("formatHeader");

        var collectionPropInfo = GetCollectionPropertyInfoFor<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(collectionPropertyExpression);
        var propertyName = collectionPropInfo.Name;
        var getCount = GetCountGetter<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(
            collectionPropertyExpression.Compile(),
            collectionPropInfo);

        // Remove old autocolumns
        dataGrid.RemoveAutoGeneratedColumns(propertyName);

        Int32 columnsRequired = items.Select(item => getCount(item)).Max();

        // Create new columns
        GenerateColumns(dataGrid,
            formatHeader,
            propertyName,
            columnsRequired);
    }    

    private static void GenerateColumns(DataGrid dataGrid,
        Func<Int32, String> formatHeader,
        String propertyName,
        Int32 columnsRequired)
    {
        for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < columnsRequired; columnNumber++)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = formatHeader(columnNumber),
                Binding = new Binding(String.Format("{0}[{1}]",
                    propertyName,
                    columnNumber))
            };

            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }


    private static Func<TItem, Int32> GetCountGetter<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(
        Func<TItem, IEnumerable<TPropertyCollectionItem>> getCollection,
        PropertyInfo propInfo)
    {
        if (getCollection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("getCollection");
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propInfo");

        var collectionType = propInfo.PropertyType;
        
        var countGetter = collectionType.GetInterfaceProperty("Count",
            typeof(Int32));

        if (countGetter != null)
        {
            return (item) =>
                (Int32)countGetter.GetMethod.Invoke(getCollection(item), null);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented: For simple IEnumerables the use of Enumerable.Count() method shall be considered.");
    }


    private static PropertyInfo GetCollectionPropertyInfoFor<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(
        Expressions.Expression<Func<TItem, 
        IEnumerable<TPropertyCollectionItem>>> propertyExpression)
    {
        if (propertyExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");
        
        var memberExp = propertyExpression.Body as Expressions.MemberExpression;
        if (memberExp == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");

        var propInfo = memberExp.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");

        if (!propInfo.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TItem)))
            throw new ArgumentException("propertyExpression");
        
        return propInfo;
    }
}
```

---

Here is the XAML:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quarter" Binding="{Binding Quarter}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And this is the code-behind:

```
using Expressions = System.Linq.Expressions

public class Item
{
    public Item(Int32 quarter, Int32 repeatColumns)
    {
        this.Quarter = quarter;
        this.MyColumns = Enumerable
            .Range(1, repeatColumns)
            .ToList();
    }

    public Int32 Quarter
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public IList<Int32> MyColumns
    {
        get; set;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Items = GetOriginalItems();

        this.DataContext = this;

        this.ReinitializeColumns();
    }

    private void ReinitializeColumns()
    {
        Expressions.Expression<Func<Item, IEnumerable<Int32>>> exp = 
            obj => 
                obj.MyColumns;

        this.dataGrid.RegenerateColumns(exp,
            this.Items);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> GetOriginalItems()
    {
        return new Item[] 
        {
            new Item(1, 3),
            new Item(2, 2),
            new Item(3, 5),
            new Item(4, 2),
        };
    }
}
```

---

## Set length

Here is the code that will create the specified amount of columns(you can put it to some standalone class because it is completely self-contained, or to the same class with arbitrary-length methods(in this case just do not forget to remove the duplicate generate methods)). It is a bit simpler and directly suits your needs:

```
    public static void RegenerateColumns<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(
       this DataGrid dataGrid,
       String propertyName,
       Int32 columnsRequired)
    {
        dataGrid.RegenerateColumns<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(propertyName,
            columnsRequired,
            index => String.Format("Column - {0}",
                index));
    }


    public static void RegenerateColumns<TItem, TPropertyCollectionItem>(
        this DataGrid dataGrid,
        String propertyName,
        Int32 columnsRequired,
        Func<Int32, String> formatHeader)
    {
        if (dataGrid == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dataGrid");
        if (propertyName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");
        if (columnsRequired < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("columnsRequired");
        if (formatHeader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("formatHeader");

        // Remove old autocolumns
        dataGrid.RemoveAutoGeneratedColumns(propertyName);
        
        GenerateColumns(dataGrid,
            formatHeader,
            propertyName,
            columnsRequired);
    }


    private static void GenerateColumns(DataGrid dataGrid,
        Func<Int32, String> formatHeader,
        String propertyName,
        Int32 columnsRequired)
    {
        for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < columnsRequired; columnNumber++)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn()
            {
                Header = formatHeader(columnNumber),
                Binding = new Binding(String.Format("{0}[{1}]",
                    propertyName,
                    columnNumber))
            };

            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }
```

And it is the code-behind that uses it:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Items = GetOriginalItems();

        this.DataContext = this;

        this.ReinitializeColumns(2);
    }

    private void ReinitializeColumns(Int32 columnsCount)
    {
        this.dataGrid.RegenerateColumns<Item, Int32>("MyColumns",
            columnsCount);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With insight given to me by Eugene on dynamics and expandoObject, this is what I implemented for solving the current problem.

here is my solution --

We have on collection coming from model, and its structure was fairly rigid.
So to bind it to a UI Grid we needed another object that maps the current list in a visually different way.

--using Expando Objects--

You can create a collection of ExpandoObjects and map its dynamic properties to the properties of you collection.

```
Dim pivotItems As Object = New ExpandoObject()
    ' set properties for object'
     pivotItems.Quarter = developmentQuarters.Key
     pivotItems.Name = developmentQuarters.Key.Name

     ' since expando obj is a dictionary for prop name and its value we can set property names dynamically like this'
     For Each developmentModel As DevelopmentModel In developmentModels
         Dim pivotAsDict As IDictionary(Of String, Object) = pivotItems
         pivotAsDict.Add(developmentModel.BusinessGroupName + " " + developmentModel.Currency.Code, developmentModel.DevelopmentPercentage)
      Next
      ReModelledItems.Add(pivotItems)
```

So now we have a nested object flattened out as a simple collection which has dynamic columns/properties generated based on values in the initial collection.

We can now simply bind this collection of ExpandoObjects